# Mimic omxplayer behavior with VLC

Tags: pi-4, omxplayer, vlc

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of `omxplayer file.mp4 --loop` using VLC since omxplayer is going to be deprecated soon.

The use case is a splash screen on an environment without X.

The closest behavior I can get is using the following command :

`vlc file.mp4 --overlay --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video --fullscreen --no-interact --intf dummy --repeat`

Though, it does not really produce the same result as the one with omxplayer.
My tests are done on a Raspbian distribution WITH a desktop environment, I notice that double-clicking on the video will exit fullscreen and show a window frame, also the console launching the command is being overlayed by a black layer. Eventually, I also face the loop is not seamless at all but this problem is quite spread so I highly doubt anyone would have a solution for that.

Which command line would you use instead of mine to be the closest to omxplayer behaviour?

Note: Issue for more information raised there: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/796